# Javascript unable to parse JSON generated by a ObjectMapper object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, fasterxml

In my current spring project, I have this Javascript/JQuery code to parse a JSON string generated by my controller:

```
<script th:if="${list}" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_content(<url to json string>, <target on html code>);

    function load_content(list, target) {
        $.get(list, function(json_string){
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON( json_string );
            $.each(json, function(index, item){
                ...
            });
        });
    }
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

the method in controller which generate this JSON is that:

```
@RequestMapping("/list.json")
@ResponseBody
public String list(@RequestParam(value="orderby", required=false) String orderby, @RequestParam(value="groupby", required=false) String groupby) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(serv.select(orderby, groupby));
}
```

Someone knows what I am missing here? Could be some bug in the implementation for `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`? If so, how to get around of it?

**UPDATE**

the json string:

```
[{"id":1,"login":"klebermo","senha":"...","nome":"kleber","sobrenome":"mota","email":"kleber@mail.com","cesta":null,"listas":[],"pedidos":[],"credenciais":[{"id":1,"nome":"categoria","autorizacoes":[{"id":1,"nome":"categoria","authority":"categoria"},{"id":2,"nome":"insert_categoria","authority":"insert_categoria"},{"id":3,"nome":"update_categoria","authority":"update_categoria"},{"id":4,"nome":"delete_categoria","authority":"delete_categoria"}],"expirationDate":null},{"id":2,"nome":"produto","autorizacoes":[{"id":5,"nome":"produto","authority":"produto"},{"id":6,"nome":"insert_produto","authority":"insert_produto"},{"id":7,"nome":"update_produto","authority":"update_produto"},{"id":8,"nome":"delete_produto","authority":"delete_produto"}],"expirationDate":null},{"id":3,"nome":"pagina","autorizacoes":[{"id":9,"nome":"pagina","authority":"pagina"},{"id":10,"nome":"insert_pagina","authority":"insert_pagina"},{"id":11,"nome":"update_pagina","authority":"update_pagina"},{"id":12,"nome":"delete_pagina","authority":"delete_pagina"}],"expirationDate":null},{"id":4,"nome":"usuario","autorizacoes":[{"id":13,"nome":"usuario","authority":"usuario"},{"id":14,"nome":"insert_usuario","authority":"insert_usuario"},{"id":15,"nome":"update_usuario","authority":"update_usuario"},{"id":16,"nome":"delete_usuario","authority":"delete_usuario"}],"expirationDate":null},{"id":5,"nome":"admin","autorizacoes":[{"id":17,"nome":"admin","authority":"admin"},{"id":18,"nome":"settings","authority":"settings"}],"expirationDate":null}],"expirationDate":null,"locked":false,"enabled":true,"authorities":[{"id":1,"nome":"categoria","authority":"categoria"},{"id":2,"nome":"insert_categoria","authority":"insert_categoria"},{"id":3,"nome":"update_categoria","authority":"update_categoria"},{"id":4,"nome":"delete_categoria","authority":"delete_categoria"},{"id":5,"nome":"produto","authority":"produto"},{"id":6,"nome":"insert_produto","authority":"insert_produto"},{"id":7,"nome":"update_produto","authority":"update_produto"},{"id":8,"nome":"delete_produto","authority":"delete_produto"},{"id":9,"nome":"pagina","authority":"pagina"},{"id":10,"nome":"insert_pagina","authority":"insert_pagina"},{"id":11,"nome":"update_pagina","authority":"update_pagina"},{"id":12,"nome":"delete_pagina","authority":"delete_pagina"},{"id":13,"nome":"usuario","authority":"usuario"},{"id":14,"nome":"insert_usuario","authority":"insert_usuario"},{"id":15,"nome":"update_usuario","authority":"update_usuario"},{"id":16,"nome":"delete_usuario","authority":"delete_usuario"},{"id":17,"nome":"admin","authority":"admin"},{"id":18,"nome":"settings","authority":"settings"}],"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":false,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"username":"klebermo","password":"..."}]
```

the error (as displayed in the browser console):

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

Comment: Can you show example JSON output and exact error from parser

Comment: @ponury-kostek update the question to include the requested info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only possible answer is that your JSON is not string, it looks like you don't need to parse anything because it's already array with object

Comment: What you mean in regards to the code? Do I need change this: `var json = jQuery.parseJSON( json_string )`? To what?

Comment: var json = json_string;